# From gallery to imageview and sharedPreferences_HELP

Tags: java, android, imageview

EDIT: I can run application, the first time i can get photo from gallery to imageView, right after that if i try it again the app freezes up,exit app and restart it, the same again!.

Issue is as follow, imageview has a button, click button, dialog opens and ask for image from gallery or image from camera.
Once i choose gallery i select image and it set the image,

BUT

sometimes the interface will just hang and freeze up giving me the not responding alert.
I tried to debug but it is like sometimes the debug does not follow the app so i can not see what is going wrong.

```
 public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
{

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

View view;
SessionManager manager;

private ImageView profilePicture;
int countrySpinnerIndex=0,citySpinnerIndex=0,areaSpinnerIndex=0;

String userName = "";
String pictureDirectory = "";
String encodedImage;

private EditText firstName_et;
private EditText lastName_et;
private  EditText email_et;
private Spinner countriesSpinner;
private Spinner citiesSpinner;
private Spinner areaSpinner;
private EditText contactNumber_et;
private EditText street_et;
private EditText areaCode_et;

private AppCompatImageButton imageEdit_btn;
private Button acceptTemp_btn;

private ArrayList<String> countriesList;
private ArrayList<String> citiesList;
private ArrayList<String> areaList;

public ProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
```

/*
Nevermind the spinners that is another hassle but not worried about that for now
*/

This is where my issue starts i think,in here i call the Asynctask for encoding the image

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            // Determine which bmp user selected in gallery and store path


            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            profilePicture.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            pictureDirectory = picturePath;
            Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) profilePicture.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            new EncodeImage(image).execute();
        }
        else if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK){

            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            profilePicture.setImageBitmap(photo);

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getContext(), photo);

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH OF BITMAP WITHIN STORAGE
            File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));


            //Temporary for display of filepath
            pictureDirectory = finalFile.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),pictureDirectory , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Glide.with(this).load(photo).into(profilePicture);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int id = v.getId();

    if(id == R.id.imageEdit_btn){

        final CharSequence[] items ={"Take Photo","Choose from Gallery","Cancel"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (items[which].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    //Open camera to user
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                } else if (items[which].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                    //open gallery to user to select image
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                } else if (items[which].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
    builder.show();
    }

    else if (id==R.id.accept_btn) {
        try {

            //Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable)((LayerDrawable)profilePicture.getDrawable()).getDrawable(0)).getBitmap();
            Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) profilePicture.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            String[] profileServerList = new String[10];

            profileServerList[0] = userName;
            profileServerList[1] = firstName_et.getText().toString();
            profileServerList[2] = lastName_et.getText().toString();
            profileServerList[3] = email_et.getText().toString();
            profileServerList[4] = contactNumber_et.getText().toString();
            profileServerList[5] = street_et.getText().toString();
            profileServerList[6] = "BWB";
            profileServerList[7] = "PE";
            profileServerList[8] = "ZA";

            //logParams[6] = areaSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
           // logParams[7] = citiesSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
           // logParams[8] = countriesSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            profileServerList[9] = areaCode_et.getText().toString();

            new AsyncUploadToServer(image, profileServerList).execute();



            //while (SyncTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING || SyncTask.getStatus()== AsyncUploadToServer.Status.PENDING) {
            // if(SyncTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
            //    SaveLocal();}
           // }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }
}
```

My Asynctask to load image into image view as well as shared preferences.

```java
public class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        boolean result;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

                manager = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

                list.add(encodedImage);
                result = manager.SetSharedPreferences(list, "ProfilePicture");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.getMessage();
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            if (result) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image was successfully stored", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image was not stored", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public class EncodeImage extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        Bitmap img;
        public EncodeImage(Bitmap image)
        {
            img = image;
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            return encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        }catch (Exception ex){
           return ex.getMessage();
        }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            new LoadImage().execute();
        }
    }

    //Used to load default profile picture
    private void Load(View view) {

        profilePicture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profileImageView);
        profilePicture.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_profile);
        //Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.default_profile).into(profilePicture);
    }
    //get image uri from camera
    private Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inPhoto) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(),inPhoto,"Title",null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
    //get actual path of image store on device
    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }

    public class AsyncUploadToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        String[] list;

        public AsyncUploadToServer(Bitmap image,String... list)
        {
            this.list = list;

           // new EncodeImage(image).execute();
           // SaveLocal();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //Background worker handling connection to database
            try
            {
              //Make an instance of the api;
                eyeWatchApi api = new eyeWatchApi();
                //Create an instance of the jason parser;
                Parser pass = new Parser();
                ArrayList<String> UpdateProfile= new ArrayList<String>();

                UpdateProfile.add(list[0]);
                UpdateProfile.add(list[1]);
                UpdateProfile.add(list[2]);
                UpdateProfile.add(list[3]);
                UpdateProfile.add(list[4]);
                UpdateProfile.add(list[5]);
                UpdateProfile.add(list[6]);
                UpdateProfile.add(list[7]);
                UpdateProfile.add(list[8]);
                UpdateProfile.add(list[9]);
                UpdateProfile.add(encodedImage);


               return pass.StringValue(api.UpdateMemberProfile(UpdateProfile));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.getMessage();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           if(result=="Success")
           {

           }
        }
    }

    public class AsyncPopulateCountrySpinner extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            countriesList = new ArrayList<String>();


            eyeWatchApi api = new eyeWatchApi();
            Parser parser = new Parser();

            try{
                countriesList = parser.CountriesArray(api.GetAllCountries());}
            catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            return "Success";
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(result == "Success") {
                ArrayAdapter<String> countriesAdapter;
                countriesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.countries_spinner_item, countriesList);
                countriesAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.countries_spinner_item_droplist);
                countriesSpinner.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#141414"));
                countriesSpinner.setAdapter(countriesAdapter);

                /*countriesSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        countrySpinnerIndex = position;
                    }
                });*/
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Could not pull Country spinner data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            //super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }

    public class AsyncPopulateCitySpinner extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


            citiesList = new ArrayList<String>();

            eyeWatchApi api = new eyeWatchApi();
            Parser parser = new Parser();

            try{
                citiesList = parser.CitiesArray(api.GetAllCities());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
            return "Success";
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(result == "Success") {

                ArrayAdapter<String> cityAdapter;

                cityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.neighborhoods_spinner_item_droplist, citiesList);
                cityAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.neighborhoods_spinner_item_droplist);
                areaSpinner.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#141414"));
                citiesSpinner.setAdapter(cityAdapter);

                /*citiesSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        citySpinnerIndex = position;
                    }
                });*/
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Could not pull City spinner data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            //super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }

    public class AsyncPopulateSuburbSpinner extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            areaList = new ArrayList<String>();


            eyeWatchApi api = new eyeWatchApi();
            Parser parser = new Parser();

            try{
                areaList =parser.SuburbArray(api.GetAllSuburbs());}
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
            return "Success";
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(result == "Success") {
               /* ArrayAdapter<String> neighAdapter;
                neighAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.neighborhood_spinner_item, areaList);
                neighAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.neighborhoods_spinner_item_droplist);
                areaSpinner.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#141414"));
                areaSpinner.setAdapter(neighAdapter);

               areaSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        areaSpinnerIndex = position;
                    }
                });*/
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Could not pull spinner data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            //super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }

      //Save profile information locally
    private void SaveLocal() {
        boolean result;

        manager = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        /*0*/list.add(firstName_et.getText().toString());
        /*1*/list.add(lastName_et.getText().toString());
        /*2*/list.add(email_et.getText().toString());
        /*3*/list.add(contactNumber_et.getText().toString());
        /*4*/list.add(street_et.getText().toString());
        /*5*/list.add("Sunridge Park");
        /*6*/list.add("Port Elizabeth");
        /*7*/list.add("South Africa");
        /*8*/list.add(areaCode_et.getText().toString());
        /*9*/list.add(encodedImage);
        /*10*/list.add("False");

        //Add to sharedpreferences local
        result = manager.SetSharedPreferences(list,"Profile");

        if (result) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data was successfully stored", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data was not stored", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void GetProfileData() {
        manager = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list = manager.GetSharedPreferences();
        try {
            firstName_et.setText(list.get(0));
            lastName_et.setText(list.get(1));
            email_et.setText(list.get(2));
            contactNumber_et.setText(list.get(3));
            street_et.setText(list.get(4));
            //area                  (5)
            //city                  (5)
            //country               (7)
            areaCode_et.setText(list.get(8));

            if (list.get(10).equals("TRUE")){
                Load(view);
            }else
            {
                String imageCode = list.get(9);
                byte[] imageBytes = Base64.decode(imageCode.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes,0,imageBytes.length);
                //Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(list.get(11));
                profilePicture.setImageBitmap(image);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vucko Thanks for the edit. If i need to remove unnecessary code please comment and i will do so

Comment: let me know if you do need the project from github to have a better look.thanks much appreciated

Comment: Might this be due to scaling of image? some images are 960 x 1280